# Add images in array to div element jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, image

Hello I'am trying to add all images of an array to an existing div tag using jQuery. Every time I try this I get the following error : *"SyntaxError: Unexpected string literal "'/>". Expected ')' to end a argument list."* 
Can anyone help me with this?

```
    </div>
    <script>
        var pictures = new Array(7);
        var counter = 0;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // sets up the array with some startin values

            pictures[0] = new Image(100, 100);
            pictures[0].src = "../Spel in jQuery/img/bubbles/blue.png";
            pictures[1] = new Image(50, 50);
            pictures[1].src = "../Spel in jQuery/img/bubbles/green.png";
            pictures[2] = new Image(50, 50);
            pictures[2].src = "../Spel in jQuery/img/bubbles/red.png";
            pictures[3] = new Image(50, 50);
            pictures[3].src = "../Spel in jQuery/img/bubbles/yellow.png";
            pictures[4] = new Image(50, 50);
            pictures[4].src = "../Spel in jQuery/img/bubbles/orange.png";
            pictures[5] = new Image(50, 50);
            pictures[5].src = "../Spel in jQuery/img/bubbles/purple.png";
            pictures[6] = new Image(50, 50);
            pictures[6].src = "../Spel in jQuery/img/bubbles/bom.png";

            $(pictures).each(function() {
                $('div#depionnen').append("<div><img src='"[0]"'</div>");

            });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I can spot an error on $('div#depionnen').append("<div><img src='"[0]"'</div>"); but it would lead to a different message, try your code on a fiddle first https://jsfiddle.net/, you may have more errors

Comment: if you still can't get it to work, then add the fiddle you created to your question so we can actually see what's happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(pictures).each(function(key, value) {
  $('div#depionnen').append("<div><img src='" + value.src + "' /></div>");
});
```